# Character encoding in xml exported from wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, character-encoding

if I export posts from Wordpress I get a huge file with the first line being

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

and some lines like this:

`<title>Sin t&iacute;tulo – Test Site</title>`

Its Spanish and references to í character. The text editor says this is an utf-8 encoded file. When I try to check the xml syntax. Says

*Reference to an entity not defined iacute*

How can I solve this syntax error? Thanks

Comment: How do you check the xml syntax?

Comment: With notepad++ with xml tools plugin and check syntax

Answer (score 0):

It's an HTML entity. https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_i.asp

Browsers know what that entity is, but an XML parser does not.

You could add a DTD reference pointing to an HTML DTD that has all of the HTML entities defined:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```